# Word wrap is not set for comment flags displayed in /admin/dashboard

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

When a very long unbroken word (for example spam) is placed in a comment flag, it distorts the admin dashboard display such that items are pushed right.

[image: Admin dashboard pushed right]

It also distorts items on the question page itself.

[image: Question page pushed right]

Chrome (Mac) Version 24.0.1312.57
SE rev 2013.2.20.514